# Local SSH port forward to different hostnames via config

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

**Context**

In my host file, I have several IPs that fall under the same designation:

```
internal.100 1.1.1.1
internal.101 2.2.2.2
internal.102 3.3.3.3
```

**Desired Outcome**

I need to port forward to port 9112 when connecting so when I open my browser and navigate to localhost:9112 I am redirected to the page I want to see

**Issues**

In my config file, I've specified that all connections to `internal.*` go to specific ports, however for the port forward to work, it needs the second half of the hostname to work.

**Config file**

```
host internal.*
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Secret.ssh
User alan
port 22
LocalForward 9112 internal.*.parse:80
```

When I port forward to any of the internal hostnames, when I open my browser and attempt to navigate to port 9112 via localhost, the server tells me it is administratively prohibited

However when I manually port forward via

```
ssh -L 9112:internal.100.parse:80 alan@1.1.1.1 -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/Secret.ssh -v
```

It port forwards successfully via local browser as the system registers that the second half (ie. 100) is in the command

What am I missing in my host file? Can I send the hostname from the command line to the config file?

Comment: When you port forward the lookup for the hostname is done on the machine you are sshing into - in your example of `-L 9112:internal.100.parse:80 alan@1.1.1.1 .... ` the machine at `1.1.1.1` is doing a lookup for `internal.100.parse` via the typical methods (hosts file, dns servers, etc)